# How can I replace symbols in the "new string" method?

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine(" {0}{1}{0}", new string('*', n * 2 - 2), new string(' ' , n + 1));
```

How can I replace the white spaces at the end of the code with something else.

Can I make it something like this?

```
new string(if ( i == n/2) {'-'} else {' '}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [conditional ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

```
new string((i == n/2) ? '-' : ' ', n + 1);
```

You could also just use a normal `if...else`:

```
char character;
if (i == n/2)
    character = '-';
else
    character = ' ';
Console.WriteLine(" {0}{1}{0}", new string('*', n * 2 - 2), new string(character , n + 1));
```